# I want query data from Jsonnb in postgress by jsonb Id

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE public.users 
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
    users jsonb
);
```

Here is the inserted data, I want get the jsonnb data by its in Postgres:

```
INSERT INTO users (users)
VALUES
    (
        '[        '[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Leanne Graham",
"username": "Bret",
"email": "Sincere@april.biz",
"address": {},
"phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
"website": "hildegard.org",
"company": {
"name": "Romaguera-Crona",
"catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
"bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Ervin Howell",
"username": "Antonette",
"email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
"address": {
"street": "Victor Plains",
"suite": "Suite 879",
"city": "Wisokyburgh",
"zipcode": "90566-7771",
"geo": {
"lat": "-43.9509",
"lng": "-34.4618"
}
]'
```

Now I want get the the data from users by in in jsonb, and make a get api in express - please help

Comment: Please just don't store arrays of user objects in a single table row. Use a proper normalised schema, and a `WHERE id = $1` query will be trivial and fast.

Comment: i could not understand pls can you explian

Comment: can give me a demo

Comment: i want make a api like a jsonplaceholder